# How to use take() operator in RxJava for lists?

Tags: java, rx-java

So i have a list

```
 List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
 strings.add("a");
 strings.add("b");
 strings.add("c");
 strings.add("d");
 strings.add("e");
 strings.add("f");
 strings.add("g");
```

I want to take just first 3 elements from the list using `RxJava` and return them back. I tried using just `take()` function but will return to me entire list because is considered as an object.

I succeeded doing something like this

```
Observable.just(strings)
            .concatMap(new Func1<List<String>, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> call(List<String> strings) {
                    return Observable.from(strings);
                }
            })
            .take(3)
            .toList()
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<String> strings) {
                    System.out.print(strings.toString());
                }
            });
```

but are many operations to do in my opinion. Is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified in this way, using `method reference`:

```
 Observable.just(strings)
            .concatMap(Observable::from)
            .take(3)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If you are not allowed to use Java 8 features, than there isn't really any method to simplify it.
Only thing I see here is not to collect it to a `List` but listen to the stream itself.

```
Observable.just(strings)
            .concatMap(new Func1<List<String>, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> call(List<String> strings) {
                    return Observable.from(strings);
                }
            })
            .take(3)
            .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String string) {
                    System.out.print(string);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Currently i don't use `Retrolambda`